# Instructions and samples for Scala on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, scala

I've spent a week googling for examples and advice on using Scala with Google App Engine, but so far I've had nothing but frustration with both Eclpise and IntelliJ IDEA in terms of trying to get a simple app up and running.

Does anyone have any advice on what the best tools are for Scala on GAE/J?

Are there any good step-by-step instructions on how to get started? Even just a project template?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do with Play 1.2.4 it's to install [gae](http://www.playframework.org/modules/gae) and [scala](http://www.playframework.org/modules/scala) modules, then create new play project:

```
play new appname --with scala
```

Add gae dependency to `appname/conf/dependencies.yml` by appending following line:

```
- play -> gae {version}
```

And in

```
appname/app/views/main.scala.html
```

you should replace
`jquery-1.5.2.min.js` with `jquery-1.6.4.min.js`
Then run it like ordinary play app:

```
play run appname
```

Comment: Please provide links when possible or some extra information. How do you add modules in dependencies.yml for example?

Comment: @zxuqlf, welcome to SO! Please provide as much detail in your answers (atleast in so far as it helps tackle the question/issues at hand). Generally, answers that lack detail, are vague or handwavy are voted down by the system. Hope this doesn't discourage you from posting great answers that you can! Have fun here at SO! :)